# applying a random variable randomly

Tags: php, string, random

I have code generating a random font and applying a new random font to each line of text and would like to add a

```
$line = str_replace ("a", "@", $line);
```

But I would like the chance of this being applied to each line to be 10% rather than applied to the string as a whole. How can i do it? Here's my existing code:

```
$fonts = array("Helvetica", "Arial", "Courier", "Georgia", "Serif", "Comic Sans", "Tahoma", "Geneva", "Times New Roman");
shuffle($fonts);

$output = "";

$lines = array_slice(file("users.txt"), -20, 20);

$i = 0;
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
  if($i == count($fonts)) {
    shuffle($fonts);
    $i = 0;
  }
  $output .= '<div style="font-size: ' . rand(15, 23) . 'px; font-family:' . $fonts[$i] . '; margin-left: ' . rand(0, 60) . '%; opacity: 0.8;">' . $line . "</div>\n";
  $i++;
    }

echo $output;
```

I'm just starting to get familiar with php, I feel as though I've got a whole new web to play with! :D

Comment: do you mean by pulling the php in to the css file or are there features of css that allow randoms and string replacements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to have 10% chance of having your 'a' changed with '@' then try inserting this  code:

```
if(rand(0, 9) == 1)
{
    $line = str_replace ("a", "@", $line);
}
```

It generates an Integer from 0 - 9 and if it equals 1 (10% chance, then it applies your formatting.

Comment: yup, little cleaner than mine too

Comment: for the record, doesnt matter what the generated number equals

Comment: as long as it's between 0 and 9!

Comment: Yes I know about the equals part, just mentioned it in order to explain the solution more thoroughly. Thanks for the "Correct answer tick" I need the Reputation points :)

Comment: that was for everyones knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

so, in te `foreach($lines as $line)` loop, add this

```
$rand = rand(0,9);
if($rand == 0)
{
    $line = str_replace("a","@",$line);
}
```

Comment: perfect, thank you, i'll be making full use of that knowledge on this project!